# In nestjs app, why payload.sub is undefined inside validate method of JwtStrategy?

Tags: nestjs, jwt

I'm working on a `nestjs` app and use `JwtStrategy` to authentication.

I generate the `access token` by singing some information include `payload.sub`:

**token.service.ts**

```
async createAccessToken(
    payload: IJwtPayload,
    expires = this.expiresInDefault,
  ): Promise<LoginResponseVm> {

    ... other codes ....

    // sign
    // here payload is contain sub property and is filled by userId
    const signedPayload = sign(payload, this.jwtKey, options);
    const token: LoginResponse = {
      accessToken: signedPayload,
      expiresIn: expires,
    };

    return this.mapperService.map<LoginResponseVm>(
      token,
      LoginResponseVm.name,
      LoginResponse.name,
    );
  }
```

[image]

**IJwtPayload.ts**

```
export interface IJwtPayload {
  sub: string;
  iat?: number;
  exp?: number;
  jti?: string;
}
```

But when run the project and fill the Authorization header of request with generated Bearer access-token and put a break-point on following validate method. payload have value but `payload.sub` is undefined! **Why?**

**jwt-strategy.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class JwtStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy) {
  constructor(
    private readonly tokenService: TokenService,
    configurationService: ConfigurationService,
  ) {
    super({
      jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromExtractors([
        ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
        ExtractJwt.fromUrlQueryParameter('access_token'),
      ]),
      secretOrKey: configurationService.JWT.Key,
      passReqToCallback: true,
    });
  }

  async validate(payload: IJwtPayload) {

    console.log(payload.sub); // <<--- Problem: payload.sub is undefined!
    const result = await this.tokenService.validatePayload(payload);
    if (!result) {
      throw new UnauthorizedException();
    }
    return result;
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I replaced this signature:

```
async validate(payload: IJwtPayload) {
```

With this one

```
async validate(req: Request, payload: IJwtPayload, done: Function) {

    const result = await this.tokenService.validatePayload(payload);
    if (!result) {
       return done(new UnauthorizedException(), false);
    }
    done(null, result);
}
```

I found above signature [here](https://codebrains.io/jwt-auth-with-nestjs-passport-and-express/).